# global variable between functions is always = None python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I have this code:

```
last_price=None

def trade(price,last_price=last_price)
  if last_price == None:
    print("last_price=None!")
    last_price = price
    #do something else

while True:
  price= get_price_function()
  trade(price)
```

Buy I have the problem - last_price is always None(it seems that it's outside the scope of function, so how to use **global variable last_price**, so it is not always none.

Comment: make trade return last price and assign it to last price in your while True loop

Comment: Declare `global last_price` in the function .

Comment: 1. Don’t use global variables in the first place. 2. If you want to assign to a global variable, you need the `global` keyword inside the function. 3. Your function shadows the global variable with a parameter of the same name. 4. This code should fail with a missing argument error because of 3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a global variable inside a function, declare it with `global` keyword.

Change your `trade` function to:

```
def trade(price)
  global last_price
  if last_price == None:
    print("last_price=None!")
    last_price = price
    #do something else
```